# how to fix pm2 unexpected token error when running npm script

Tags: npm, pm2

I am trying to run an **npm** script with **pm2** on **Windows 10**,
but the configuration is not working as expected.

```
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC
OS Version: 10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044
```

**pm2 --version** `5.3.0`

**node -v** `v20.0.0`

**npm -v** `9.6.5`

##### run:

`pm2 start pm2.config.js`

##### pm2.config.js

```
function conf_www(){
    
    const { parsed } = require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' })

    const { mode, www_host, www_port, api_host } = parsed

    console.log('[-] pm2 - pm2.config.js - conf_www -', mode, www_host, www_port, api_host)

    return {

        name: 'www',
        cwd: './',
        script: 'npx',
        args: 'webpack serve',
        autorestart: false,
        env: { mode, www_host, www_port, api_host }
    }
}

function conf_srv(){
    
    const { parsed } = require('dotenv').config({ path: './srv/.env' })

    const { mode, srv_host, srv_port } = parsed

    console.log('[-] pm2 - pm2.config.js - conf_srv -', mode, srv_host, srv_port)

    return {

        name: 'srv',
        cwd: './srv',
        script: 'npm',
        args: 'start',
        autorestart: false,
        env: { mode, srv_host, srv_port }
    }
}

module.exports = { apps : [ conf_srv(), conf_www() ] }
```

##### output:

```
0|www      | C:\Users\_\apps\node\npm.cmd:1
0|www      | @ECHO off
0|www      | ^
0|www      |
0|www      | SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
0|www      |     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
0|www      |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1187:20)
0|www      |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:27)
0|www      |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
0|www      |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
0|www      |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
0|www      |     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\_\apps\node\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
0|www      |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
0|www      |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
0|www      |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
```

#### Possible Solution:

Should I provide a custom js script starting npm as a subprocess?

Got it working by changing the script path to
`script: require('os').platform() === 'win32' ? 'C:\\Users\\_\\apps\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npx-cli.js' : '/usr/local/bin/npx',`

, but it will open a cmd window, which when closed, will terminate the process. It won't run in the background.